# SSRS date sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a date that I want to show as Month then Year like 'Jan 05'.
I have used the following SQL  datename(month,eFolder.eCreationTime) + ' ' + datename(year,eFolder.eCreationTime)  as "MonthYear" in my query.

However on SSRS I am finding it difficult to sort this in a column grouping as its showing in Alphabetical order. Is there anyway to sort this or does the problem lie with the SQL mentioned above as its concatenating it
I have tried sorting at group level and on the textbox with no success.

Thank you in advance

This is how the sql looks like at the minute

```
SELECT
case when SUBSTRING(eFolder.eFolderName,1,2) = 'IM' then 'Incidents' 
     when SUBSTRING(eFolder.eFolderName,1,2) = 'RF' then 'Requests'
     else null end "Request or Incident", 
  count(eFolder.eFolderName) as "Log No",
  eUser2.eDistinguishedName,
    datename(month,eFolder.eCreationTime) + ' ' + datename(year,eFolder.eCreationTime)  as "Month"

FROM
  eUser  eUser2 RIGHT OUTER JOIN prcIncidentManagement ON (eUser2.eUserName=prcIncidentManagement.AssignedTo)
   INNER JOIN eFolder ON (prcIncidentManagement.EFOLDERID=eFolder.eFolderID)



group by 

case when SUBSTRING(eFolder.eFolderName,1,2) = 'IM' then 'Incidents' 
     when SUBSTRING(eFolder.eFolderName,1,2) = 'RF' then 'Requests'
     else null end , 
  eUser2.eDistinguishedName,
   datename(month,eFolder.eCreationTime) + ' ' + datename(year,eFolder.eCreationTime)
```

Comment: one option is to send the Date to SSRS and let SSRS format it.. Or include another field un-formatted for sorting in SSRS

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the string conversion in SQL.  Return the data as a date value and do the string formatting in SSRS.

One of many reasons why dates should not be stored (or retrieved) as text.

> The reason I grouped it to months is to reduce the amount of lines and time it takes.

You can still group it by month without converting it to a string.  Just return a date that represents that month (e.g. `2015-10-01`)

Other options:

- Groups by the Year and Month as numbers an include them in your results and turn that into a date in SSRS
- Parse the string to a date in SSRS (using `CDate` or `DateTime.ParseExact()`)

Comment: Hiya, thank you,  however the query itself takes too long to run when its raw as in the date itself is for example is 01/01/2015 bringing back many lines without grouping it. The reason I grouped it to months is to reduce the amount of lines and time it takes. So no way around it? Ideally I want to see the data in month level.

Comment: You can still group it by month without converting it to a string.  Just return a date that represents that month (e.g. `2015-10-01`)

Comment: Hiya, could you possible show me an example of how to do this, this is how the sql looks like at the minute if you wanted to know.

Comment: Sorry, I needed to add the sql to the main post as there is a limit here. Thank you